# How to use angular material select with a button (without form field)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to use the angular material `mat-select` component without the `mat-form-field`, I want it to be conceptually similar to the native select element. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You should be able to use it on its own. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Edric Right, but I want it to be styled nicely, it should look like a button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple approach is to use a `mat-menu` and update the trigger on button-click.

[demo using mat-menu component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-option-select).

If you don't want to use a menu but a `mat-select`, here is a solution which uses the select component and also ensures the panel is positioned properly when opened:

[demo using mat-select component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-button-select)

1. insert the `select` in a `button` component.
2. position and size the select to cover the button.
3. make the `select` opacity 0 so it's not seen.
4. call the `open()` method on button `click`.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and just use the mat-menu